# How do you move and position your content in html

Tags: html, css, position

I'm moving my code to integrate into a website.But I can't seem to get my content in the particular position that I want,when I try absolute position the formatting within the content itself messes up and I have no idea how to continue.
For example,I would want to shift it somewhere in the middle of website.
Would appreciate the help

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <title>News page</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        /* To align the articles left to right rather than up to down*/
    #newssection article{
            width: 275px;
            display: inline-block;
            *display: inline;
            zoom:1;
            vertical-align: top;
            margin: 0 38px 0 0;}
          /* To add background to the photos as well as resizing*/
       article > img {height:250px;
           width:250px;
       background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #68EACC 0%, #497BE8 100;%}

        /* To draw line above and below latest happening*/
        .line{
    width: 300px;
    height: 3px;
    background: url('newimg/line.png') repeat-x ;
    margin-bottom: 10px;}

        /* color when hovering read more*/
        .read:hover{
    background-color: #60EC10;}
    </style>

</head>

<body>

    <div>
        <div class="line"></div>
        <h1>Latest Happening</h1>
        <div class="line"></div>

    </div>

    <div id="newssection">
        <article>
    <h1>Foreign exchange was a success</h1>
    <img src="newimg/success.jpg" alt="" />
    <p>content</p>
    <a href="fullwidth.html" class="read">Read More</a>
    </article>

    <article>
    <h1>Congratulations to our winners</h1>
    <img src="newimg/winner.jpg" alt="" />
    <p>content</p>
    <a href="fullwidth.html" class="read">Read More</a>
    </article>

    <article class="lastarticle">
    <h1>Unknown bear species found in school grounds</h1>
    <img src="newimg/bear.jpg" alt="" />
    <p>content</p>
    <a href="fullwidth.html" class="read">Read More</a>
    </article>

    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You use `margin` and `padding`. Can you add your html?

Answer (score 0):

For the heading, try

```
h1 { text-align: center; }
```

For the newssection

```
#newssection {
   width:1000px;
   margin:auto;
}
```

This will keep the newssection at the center.

Answer (score 0):

Some error found in your css code, fixed the css errors, and add extra div `main-conatiner` and add `text-align:center`

```css
#newssection article{
width: 275px;
display: inline-block;
display: inline;
zoom:1;
vertical-align: top;
margin: 0 38px 0 0;}

article > img {height:250px;
width:250px;
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #68EACC 0%, #497BE8 100);
}
.line{
width: 300px;
height: 3px;
background: url('newimg/line.png') repeat-x ;
margin-bottom: 10px;}


/* color when hovering read more*/
.read:hover{
background-color: #60EC10;}

.main-container
{
padding-left:100px;
padding-top:100px;
padding-right:100px;
padding-bottom:100px;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>News page</title>

</head>

<body>
<div class="main-container">
    <div>
        <div class="line"></div>
        <h1>Latest Happening</h1>
        <div class="line"></div>

    </div>

    <div id="newssection">
        <article>
    <h1>Foreign exchange was a success</h1>
    <img src="newimg/success.jpg" alt="" />
    <p>content</p>
    <a href="fullwidth.html" class="read">Read More</a>
    </article>

    <article>
    <h1>Congratulations to our winners</h1>
    <img src="newimg/winner.jpg" alt="" />
    <p>content</p>
    <a href="fullwidth.html" class="read">Read More</a>
    </article>

    <article class="lastarticle">
    <h1>Unknown bear species found in school grounds</h1>
    <img src="newimg/bear.jpg" alt="" />
    <p>content</p>
    <a href="fullwidth.html" class="read">Read More</a>
    </article>

    </div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I've tried it and it centers but it changes my original orientation which is left to right.

Comment: where yu want  to change position?

Comment: the center is fine.But I would prefer something that allows you to specifiy the coordinates. Like if you compare my original code,the news post are displayed left to right instead of up to down.

Comment: please provide any example? what u need??

Comment: You need to position any item or content?

Comment: I need the main-container to not change the orientation of the content and a different css tag other than center align which can be used place the container specifically where i want, example,500 pxs to the left 200 from top

Comment: updated the snippet, change the padding on each side, if u want to add left 500px, give padding-left:500px;